# Logstash 5.0 with input websocket - unable to stdout json data

Tags: sockets, websocket, logstash

I have the following environment:

```
/usr/share/logstash# bin/logstash --path.settings=/etc/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/stream.conf -V

Sending Logstash logs to /var/log/logstash which is now configured via log4j2.properties.
logstash 5.0.0
jruby 1.7.25 (1.9.3p551) 2016-04-13 867cb81 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit     Server VM 1.8.0_111-b14 +jit [linux-amd64]
java 1.8.0_111 (Oracle Corporation)
jvm Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM / 25.111-b14
```

I installed the following 2 repos

- logstash-input-websocket version 3.0.2
- ruby-ftw [http://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-ftw"](http://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-ftw%22)

I created both gems by running gem install .gemspec file.

My Gemfile under /usr/share/logstash folder was modified to add those 2 lines.

```
gem "logstash-input-websocket", :path => "/home/xav/source/logstash-input-websocket-master"
gem "ftw", :path => "/home/xav/source/ruby-ftw-master"
```

I know my logstash configuration is ok ( I checked it with -t option).
Furthermore, on purpose I modified my stream.conf file to omit the url definition for the input websocket to make sure the plugin was being used.
I got the expected error in the /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log file as below:

```
xav@xav-VirtualBox:/var/log/logstash$ tail -f logstash-plain.log 
[2016-11-01T11:40:28,998][ERROR][logstash.inputs.websocket] Missing a required setting for the websocket input plugin:

  input {
    websocket {
      url => # SETTING MISSING
      ...
   }
 }
[2016-11-01T11:40:29,011][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] fetched an   invalid config {:config=>"\ninput {\n  websocket {\n     mode => client\n}\n}\n\noutput {\n\n  stdout { }\n}\n\n", :reason=>"Something is wrong with your configuration."
```

I edited the stream.conf file to add the wss url I want to read the json 
output from with:

```
input {
 websocket {
    mode => client
    url => "wss://<my-url-to-websocket/something"}
}
output {    
stdout { }
}
```

I run logstash again. Everything seems to be working fine BUT I don't get anything in my stdout. The log file output is:

```
    11-01T12:09:25,968][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] -------- Logstash Settings (* means modified) ---------
11-01T12:09:25,980][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] node.name: "xav-VirtualBox"
11-01T12:09:25,981][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/stream.conf"
11-01T12:09:25,981][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *path.data: "/var/lib/logstash" (default: "/usr/share/logstash/data")
11-01T12:09:25,981][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.test_and_exit: false
11-01T12:09:25,981][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.reload.automatic: false
11-01T12:09:25,981][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.reload.interval: 3
11-01T12:09:25,982][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] metric.collect: true
11-01T12:09:25,982][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.id: "main"
11-01T12:09:25,982][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.workers: 1
11-01T12:09:25,982][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.output.workers: 1
11-01T12:09:25,983][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.batch.size: 125
11-01T12:09:25,983][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.batch.delay: 5
11-01T12:09:25,983][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.unsafe_shutdown: false
11-01T12:09:25,983][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.plugins: []
11-01T12:09:25,984][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.debug: false
11-01T12:09:25,984][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *log.level: "debug" (default: "info")
11-01T12:09:25,984][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] version: false
11-01T12:09:25,984][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] help: false
11-01T12:09:25,984][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] log.format: "plain"
11-01T12:09:25,984][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] http.host: "127.0.0.1"
11-01T12:09:25,984][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] http.port: 9600..9700
11-01T12:09:25,986][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] http.environment: "production"
11-01T12:09:25,986][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *path.settings: "/etc/logstash" (default: "/usr/share/logstash/config")
11-01T12:09:25,986][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *path.logs: "/var/log/logstash" (default: "/usr/share/logstash/logs")
11-01T12:09:25,987][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] --------------- Logstash Settings -------------------
11-01T12:09:26,039][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Agent: Configuring metric collection
11-01T12:09:26,043][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.os] PeriodicPoller: Starting {:polling_interval=>1, :polling_timeout=>60}
11-01T12:09:26,049][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] PeriodicPoller: Starting {:polling_interval=>1, :polling_timeout=>60}
11-01T12:09:26,122][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Reading config file {:config_file=>"/etc/logstash/conf.d/stream.conf"}
11-01T12:09:26,197][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.json     ] config LogStash::Codecs::JSON/@id = "json_982d8975-bd47-4f64-8a68-0da7e7a59a55"
11-01T12:09:26,198][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.json     ] config LogStash::Codecs::JSON/@enable_metric = true
11-01T12:09:26,198][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.json     ] config LogStash::Codecs::JSON/@charset = "UTF-8"
11-01T12:09:26,202][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.websocket] config LogStash::Inputs::Websocket/@mode = "client"
11-01T12:09:26,202][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.websocket] config LogStash::Inputs::Websocket/@url = "wss://REDACTED"
11-01T12:09:26,202][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.websocket] config LogStash::Inputs::Websocket/@id = "93ebfb1d0936097ee295b418952f2dab3abb3ef8-1"
11-01T12:09:26,203][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.websocket] config LogStash::Inputs::Websocket/@enable_metric = true
11-01T12:09:26,203][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.websocket] config LogStash::Inputs::Websocket/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::JSON id=>"json_982d8975-bd47-4f64-8a68-0da7e7a59a55", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">
11-01T12:09:26,203][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.websocket] config LogStash::Inputs::Websocket/@add_field = {}
11-01T12:09:26,211][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.line     ] config LogStash::Codecs::Line/@id = "line_a255b752-4d76-4933-b4d3-e76e427bbddb"
11-01T12:09:26,214][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.line     ] config LogStash::Codecs::Line/@enable_metric = true
11-01T12:09:26,215][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.line     ] config LogStash::Codecs::Line/@charset = "UTF-8"
11-01T12:09:26,215][DEBUG][logstash.codecs.line     ] config LogStash::Codecs::Line/@delimiter = "\n"
11-01T12:09:26,218][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.stdout  ] config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@id = "93ebfb1d0936097ee295b418952f2dab3abb3ef8-2"
11-01T12:09:26,219][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.stdout  ] config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@enable_metric = true
11-01T12:09:26,219][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.stdout  ] config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Line id=>"line_a255b752-4d76-4933-b4d3-e76e427bbddb", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8", delimiter=>"\n">
11-01T12:09:26,219][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.stdout  ] config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@workers = 1
11-01T12:09:26,238][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] starting agent
11-01T12:09:26,242][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] starting pipeline {:id=>"main"}
11-01T12:09:26,650][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>125}
11-01T12:09:26,654][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
11-01T12:09:26,676][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Starting puma
11-01T12:09:26,682][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Trying to start WebServer {:port=>9600}
11-01T12:09:26,688][DEBUG][logstash.api.service     ] [api-service] start
11-01T12:09:26,748][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
11-01T12:09:27,038][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.collector] Collector: Sending snapshot to observers {:created_at=>2016-11-01 12:09:27 -0400}
11-01T12:09:28,053][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.collector] Collector: Sending snapshot to observers {:created_at=>2016-11-01 12:09:28 -0400}
11-01T12:09:29,060][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.collector] Collector: Sending snapshot to observers {:created_at=>2016-11-01 12:09:29 -0400}
11-01T12:09:30,100][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.collector] Collector: Sending snapshot to observers {:created_at=>2016-11-01 12:09:30 -0400}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Nobody is using this ? :)